# How to compile WordNet-3.0 on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: compiler-errors, tcl, tk-toolkit, wordnet, ubuntu-17.10

I need to install and work with WordNet (current version 3.0) on my Ubuntu distro 17.10. I have installed all dependencies (tcl/tk) and, after the developers instructions, I follow the usual 
`./configure
make
make install`

process.

I untared the package and when, inside the directory, I type `./configure.sh`, it works with no errors:

`WordNet is now configured 
 Installation directory:       /usr/local/WordNet-3.0`

etc.

When I now run `make` I get:

```
compilation terminated.
Makefile:267: recipe for target 'libWN_a-binsrch.o' failed
make[3]: *** [libWN_a-binsrch.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/user/WordNet/WordNet-3.0/lib'
Makefile:372: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/WordNet/WordNet-3.0/lib'
Makefile:218: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/WordNet/WordNet-3.0'
Makefile:156: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

If I run
`sudo make`
I get:

```
compilation terminated.
Makefile:273: recipe for target 'wishwn-tkAppInit.o' failed
make[2]: *** [wishwn-tkAppInit.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/WordNet/WordNet-3.0/src'
Makefile:218: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/WordNet/WordNet-3.0'
Makefile:156: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

(same error I get if I type `make` again, after and ever after `sudo make`).

In the distributed README and INSTALL texts of the program I didn't find any relevant info.

Any insight?

Thanks!

Comment: What does it say immediately before the line that says `compilation terminated.`? Right now, it's apparently saying the equivalent of “it didn't work” and that's not something we can really help with on its own. We need more detail, _specifically_ detail that describes what actually went wrong…

Answer (score 3):

WordNet 3.0 seems to access Tcl internals in an deprecated way (`interp->result`).

Try to compile with `CFLAGS=-DUSE_INTERP_RESULT make` - this enables legacy access to `interp->result`.

From the [man page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclLib/Interp.htm):

> For legacy programs and extensions no longer being maintained, compiles against the Tcl 8.6 header files are only possible with the compiler directives
>
> `#define USE_INTERP_RESULT`
>
> and/or
>
> `#define USE_INTERP_ERRORLINE`
>
> depending on which fields of the Tcl_Interp struct are accessed. These directives may be embedded in code or supplied via compiler options.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/372480/tcl-error-while-installing-wordnet/372579#372579